# PHP string does not work in MYSQL IN()

Tags: php, mysql, implode

I just add code because it will say everything. And yes, it does not work and I dont know why :(

```
$array = array('One', 'Two', 'Three');
$string = "'" . implode("', '", $array) . "'";

$query = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE name IN (" . $string . ")";
$make = $this->conn->prepare($query);
$make->execute();
$result = $make->fetchAll();
```

It returns empty array. Thank you for your help.

Comment: [`check_for_errors($this->conn)`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) on `execute()`.

Comment: Echo out your query. Does it look like you think it should? Take advantage of binding parameters, so you don't have to encapsulate it yourself.

Comment: I use PDO, and it echo every error for me. The problem is that the imploded string is actually "not a string" but I dont know why. When I write it by myself, it works...

Comment: Are you sure you have the `$table` defined properly?

Comment: Yes I am, because when I echo imploded array and paste string inside IN(), it works.

Comment: Look in your error logs. Because you're assuming the query should run, the error logs (or error reporting, enabled) will give you lot's of valuable insight as to what is going on here. I *strongly suspect* that `$table` is not be set properly.

Comment: When I echo my query it looks like this:
SELECT * FROM steam WHERE name IN ('AWP | Hyper Beast', 'StatTrak™ AWP | Hyper Beast', 'AWP | Man-o'-war', 'StatTrak™ AWP | Man-o'-war', 'AWP | Asiimov', 'StatTrak™ AWP | Asiimov')

Comment: There you go - `Man-o'-War` is burping your query. You should use prepared statements.

Comment: OK, I added bindParam, but still nothing :(

Comment: Pass the array in your execute statement: `$make->execute($array);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes in because you have single quotes in the values you're trying to pass to the table, i.e. *"Man-o'-War"*.

Because you're using an array and a prepared statement you should pass the array when you execute the query:

```
$array = array('One', 'Two', 'Three');

$query = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE name IN (" . implode(',',str_split(str_repeat('?',count($array)))).") ";
$make = $this->conn->prepare($query);
$make->execute($array);
$result = $make->fetchAll();
```

To insure we have enough positional placeholders we perform a little magic with [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php), [`str_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) and [`str_repeat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php) to get enough `?` in the statement.

From [Demystifying PHP's Data Objects (PDO)](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html)

> YOU MUST pass all values to bind in an ***array*** to `PDOStatement->execute()` or you have to bind every value with `PDOStatement->bindValue()`, then call `PDOStatement->execute()` with no parameters. Passing an array (empty or not) to `execute()` will replace any previous bindings and can lead to errors, e.g. with MySQL the error "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2031" (CR_PARAMS_NOT_BOUND) if you passed an empty array.

One other note, make sure that `$table` is properly populated (and *no*, you cannot pass table or column names as parameters in PDO).

Comment: Now it made an error:
Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Comment: *I knew you would pull this off Sam!* - @JayBlanchard

Comment: *Yep Ralph, once we eyeballed the real problem it was like eating cake in a barrel!* @Fred-ii-

Comment: *Better than fish in a barrel, any day Sam* - @JayBlanchard ;-)